# spinnaker deck not listening at port 9000

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Installed spinnaker via halyard on ubuntu 14.04 machine using the commands below.

hal version list
VERSION=1.4.2
hal config version edit --version $VERSION
sudo hal deploy apply
hal deploy connect

but deck is not listening at port 9000, netstat -l does not show port 9000.
Checked the spinnaker logs and they aren't any errors.

although the /opt/spinnaker/config/spinnaker.yml  has the right configuration for deck

```
deck:  
   port: 9000   
   address: localhost  
   host: localhost  
   scheme: http  
   env: {}  
   artifactId: spinnaker-deck=1.6.2-20171002182452  
   kubernetes:  
     imagePullSecrets: []  
   enabled: true  
   monitored: false  
   sidecar: false  
   safeToUpdate: true  
   targetSize: 1  
   skipLiveCycleManagement: false  
   baseUrl: http://localhost:9000
```

Also the apache2/port.conf has this
Listen localhost:9000

Is there a way to find out what went wrong and bring the deck up?

Answer (score 0):

I was also running in to the same issue till I saw something strange on the console while running `hal deploy apply`. There is some issue with apache not able to reload:

`Setting up ssl-cert (1.0.33) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.34~rc-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up spinnaker-deck (2.0.0-20171108151529) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.13) ...
null: unrecognized service
Enabling site spinnaker.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 reload
Site 000-default disabled.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 reload
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  spinnaker-front50
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.`

I reloaded apache manually and after that I could see deck listening on port 9000.
There is an open issue which we created: https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/2210
Hope this helps.